# How to save selected item from viewPager in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i have this fragment to handle 3 items with viewPager:

onCreateView:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ejournal, container, false)
    viewPager2 = view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_main)
    tabs = view.findViewById(R.id.tabs_main)
    item1 = view.findViewById(R.id.item1);
    item1.setText("My Planner")
    item2 = view.findViewById(R.id.item2);
    item2.setText("My Heart")
    item3 = view.findViewById(R.id.item3);
    item3.setText("My Soul")
    item1.setOnClickListener(this);
    item2.setOnClickListener(this);
    item3.setOnClickListener(this);
    def = item2.getTextColors();
    val fragmentAdapter = EjournalAdapter(childFragmentManager)
    viewPager2.adapter = fragmentAdapter
    viewPager2.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager2)
    return view
}
```

onClick Function:

```
override fun onClick(view: View) {
    if(view.id == R.id.item1)
    {
        item1.setTextColor(R.color.maincolor_purple)
        item1.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            requireContext(),
            R.drawable.tab_bg_selected
        )
        item2.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            requireContext(),
            R.drawable.tab_bg_unselected

        )
        item3.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            requireContext(),
            R.drawable.tab_bg_unselected
        )
        item1.elevation = 3F
        item2.elevation = 2F
        item3.elevation = 1F
        item2.setTextColor(def);
        item3.setTextColor(def);
        viewPager2.setCurrentItem(0)


    }
    else if (view.id == R.id.item2)
    {
        item1.setTextColor(def)
        item1.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            requireContext(),
            R.drawable.tab_bg_unselected
        )
        item2.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            requireContext(),
            R.drawable.tab_bg_selected
        )
        item3.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            requireContext(),
            R.drawable.tab_bg_unselected
        )
        item2.setTextColor(R.color.maincolor_purple)

        item1.elevation = 1F
        item2.elevation = 3F
        item3.elevation = 2F
        item3.setTextColor(def)
        val size = item2.width
        viewPager2.setCurrentItem(1)
    }
    else if (view.id == R.id.item3)
    {
        item1.setTextColor(def)
        item1.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            requireContext(),
            R.drawable.tab_bg_unselected
        )
        item2.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            requireContext(),
            R.drawable.tab_bg_unselected
        )
        item3.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
            requireContext(),
            R.drawable.tab_bg_selected
        )
        item3.setTextColor(R.color.maincolor_purple)
        item1.elevation = 1F
        item2.elevation = 2F
        item3.elevation = 3F
        item2.setTextColor(def)
        val size = item2.width * 2
        viewPager2.setCurrentItem(2)
    }
}
```

so above code is in one fragment and each item will navigate to different fragment

everything is working but when i click any item to navigate to different fragment and press back from that fragment to return to this the item selection will always get back to the first item

for example, item2 will navigate to "My Heart" fragment and when i press back from "My Heart" fragment i want the item selected is "My Heart" item

how to achieve this?

in the other fragment I'm calling:

```
getActivity()?.onBackPressed();
```

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1:

You are trying to do what is called as `Sharing State between fragments`
It is better to use `ViewModel` which is a part of  `Android Jetpack`

The Android docs have a beautiful explanation of how to do so [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)

If you are looking for a Java Example, you can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/codinginflow/84ef0cf9673e8ef4a24ad61fbdaf45aa)

Approach 2:

An alternative approach would be to create an interface in the activity and share it between the two fragments. The fragment that is returning the data should call the method of the interface and the fragment that is receiving the data should implement the interface and observe the data in the fragment when it is called